# How to configure git repository to warn/reject when commits contain certain keywords

Tags: git, gitlab

Lets say theres somebody working on one of my projects who is very stupid sometimes, and leaves byebug calls in when pushing to master(who may or may not be me)

Is there any way to configure a gitlab repository to warn/reject pushes that contain certain keywords? I've seen config options to reject force pushes, is there a keyword filter configuration option, or something that could be used to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a server-side [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

To do so in the Gitlab, you need some [tweaks](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/hooks/custom_hooks.html).
You must place a script in

```
/home/git/repositories/<group>/<project>.git
```

create the custom_hooks directory
then place your hook in a file with the name "pre-receive" on it, and give it execution permission

Remember, for doing so, you must be the Gitlab admin - or a friend of him.

An example of a hook for starting with is shown [here](https://gist.github.com/caniszczyk/1327469).
For doing what you want, I think this script ( with some fixing, it is just a skeleton), may work.

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python from commands import getoutput as cmd
> import sys
> improper_words = ["byebug","bye", for line in sys.stdin:
> words = cmd("git log " + line).split(" ")
> for improper in improper_words:
>     if improper in words:
>        sys.exit(1) sys.exit(0)
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add hooks to do it.
Your hook should verify the code and ACCEPT/REJECT the commit based upon the outcome.

You should use the `pre-commit` hook
http://codeinthehole.com/writing/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/

---

#### More info about hooks:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks/
http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Comment: thank you very much! i wish I could accept both answers